# Page down SendKeys not working C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sendkeys

So a piece of my code is:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{PGDN}");
```

This code is sending the number 3 to the program I'm using.
The Page Down button, above the arrows on my keyboard is necessary for a program and it has a function...
This key has a different function than the Page Down button on the keypad.

Is anyone aware of a way around having `SendKeys.SendWait(...)` send the Page Down button on the keyboard, rather than the "3" on the numpad?

Comment: Have you tried turning numlock on/off? Seems like an interaction with that.

Comment: I have indeed.  When turning numlock off, there is no output at all.  The client that I am interacting with uses the "Page Down" key exclusively.  I'm currently trying to find a way to remap that key to the numpad.

Comment: Have you tried setting focus to the window or field first as well + numlock being off?

Comment: Indeed.  I have came to the conclusion that when SendKeys is sending a page down press, it is using the one on the numpad.  The Page Down button is the one that is mapped in the client I am interacting with.  I'm going to see if I can find some more raw info into actually simulating the data from that keypress, or writing my own sendkey method for it.

Comment: Ah, yeah I have not been able to find anything either, but I am guessing you set the key with the Keys.PageDown so might be a way to simulate it using that.

Comment: Yes I agree that I have found that the key enumeration for pgdn, is Keys.Next, which is not what I need.  I need Keys.PageDown.

Comment: Keys.Next may very well be the true PageDown you are looking for. The names aren't the greatest as if you ever at look the VirtualKey constants on MSDN looking for the left Alt key, it is really the `LMENU` value you have to send in.

Comment: TyCobb it may be, but either way it's sending the wrong key. http://www.ultimarc.com/images/kb102.gif     According to this layout, I need to be sending key 86 instead of key 103 which is the key it sends.  I tried mapping the key to the numpad key, and that didn't work...for good reason. I am going to have to find a way to send the value that would be sent by that key, which is proving to be difficult.

Comment: Try pinvoking `SendInput` and use this sheet: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731.aspx    I am thinking you may be looking at the wrong key values. If I recall correctly, the .NET form `Keys` doesn't match the same values a lot of resources show for native calls. There is also a nice library that works really well called Windows Input Simulator (make to get the version from NuGet as codeplex is way out of date).

Comment: Thank you TyCobb, I will give this a shot tomorrow at work!  It looks pretty promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my conclusion was quite simple.  Using the InputSimulator as TyCobb recommended, I was able to properly simulate virtual key codes, and everything was smooth.

Comment: Consider adding the relevant solution code to your answer so others can benefit from that.